# Onedrive new api, Resumable item upload fail when token expires

Tags: onedrive

I have a problem with "Resumable item upload" (http://onedrive.github.io/items/upload_large_files.htm).
If the access token expires during the upload session I receive a 401 Unhautorized error even if I use the refresh token to obtnain another access token.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to handle this in your application - refresh token if this happens and then continue uploading. Current chunk should be properly saved so you can continue with the next one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I refresh the token before it expires (access token expres in 1 hour, I request another one after 55 minutes). You suggest to refresh the token after the expiration and retry to upload a chunk?

Comment: When you finish uploading a chunk and it returns that token expired, you just refresh token and continue with next chunk. You don't have to retry.